# Bare Plural Nouns or the + Plural

Tags: definite-article

I've been thinking about plural nouns and the definite article (which is a much-discussed subject among scientists)
and I am beginning to think that with plural nouns the use of "the" depends on how close the noun is associated with the context
have a look at the following examples:

> **_waiters** in Texas are very polite

- waiters are not the first thing that comes to mind when talking about Texas, it is not a close association. Thus we shouldn't use "the"

> **_waiters** in Austin are very polite

- here we have a narrower context, talking about a city, however, waiters are still not the first thing invoked in our imagination when we're talking about Austin.

> the waiters in  El Patio are very polite

- here we're are talking about one specific restaurant (El patio) and I believe that "the" is obligatory, unlike the first 2 examples, where "zero" is preferable.

Is the use of articles in those sentences correct?
What if I change "**in** Austin" to "**of** Austin"? I believe it could affect the choice of article, couldn't it?

Comment: If you're referring to a particular restaurant, I would usually say "the waiters **at** El Patio", not "*in* El Patio".

Comment: Thank you!  What If I am reffering to a chain of restaurants, should I still use the waiters or just waiters?

Comment: I would use **the** (and **at**). I would probably say "The waiters at McDonalds" whether I was referring to one restaurant or the chain as a whole. (Might depend on context.)

Comment: Your premise is wrong; we can, indeed, use "the" in your first example (the one with "Texas"). You should really refer to the guidance for using the definite article as given in common and widely respected grammars; they are generally correct.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan 
Any chance you can recommend any of the respected books you've mentioned?
Most of the ones I've read confine themselves to using quite ambiguous terms and grammar models, which have little application when it comes to practice and usage of articles.

Comment: @Mr.PastProgressive I can't name any offhand for that specific topic, but this site maintains [a list of recommended resources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english), and some of those certainly address the issue. I think that major books such as Longman and CGEL are most likely to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your grammar is good but your reasoning is not so good. I would relate it more to the fact that you are referring to a class of people. In the examples you have given, the size of the class goes from larger to smaller. The smaller the class or group referred to, the more likely you are to be including every member of the class. For example:

- Dogs in pet shops sell for about $300.
- The dogs in our pet shop sell for about $300.

In the first example, you could find a case of one dog selling for $1,000, but it wouldn't invalidate the general statement. Likewise, when I read "waiters in Texas are very polite" I take that as your general but not necessarily universal experience of the waiters there.